# Conditional select in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have below requirement

```
INSERT INTO #test VALUES('20210109', 12, 1),
('20210109', 12, 0),
('20210131', 12, 0),
('20210131', 12, 0),
('20210131', 12, 0),
('20210225', 23, 1),
('20210225', 23, 0),
('20210228', 23, 1),
('20210315', 56, 1),
('20210326', 45, 1),
('20210328', 45, 1),
('20210327', 56, 1)
,('20210328', 45, 0),
('20210327', 56, 0);
```

for above  dataset, I would like to select all records with 1 for the same date and If I don't see a 1, select zero. Is it possible to write this in one query. 
Final result

```
'20210109', 12, 1 
'20210131', 12, 0
'20210225', 23, 1
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can just use aggregation with `max()`:

```
select col1, col2, max(col3)
from #test
group by col1, col2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could left join a query of 1s on a query of 0s and `coalesce` the result:

```sql
SELECT    COALESCE(ones.col1, zeros.col1),
          COALESCE(ones.col2, zeros.col2),
          COALESCE(ones.col3, zeros.col3)
FROM      (SELECT col1, col2, col3
           FROM   #test
           WHERE  col3 = 1) ones
LEFT JOIN (SELECT col1, col2, col3
           FROM   #test
           WHERE  col3 = 0) zeroes on ones.col1 = zeros.col1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this or use max() like mentioned by Mr. Gordon above.

```
    select col1, col2, case when sum(col3) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as col3
    from #test 
    group by col1, col2;
```

this will check if there will be a result in col3 greater than 0.